# Enable/disable checkbox determind by users input

Tags: javascript

I've got a simple form where the user enters his contact number. If the contact number starts with 07 then the checkbox is enabled anything else I need it to be disabled.

I have written some code but the problem I face is when the user types 01 then it's disabled but if they then go on to add any other numbers after the 01 the checkbox becomes enabled.

```js
function deselectcheckbox(wildvalue) {
  if (document.getElementById("1").value == "01") {
   $("#checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
   document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "Not able to send";
  }
  else
   {
   $("#checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
   document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "Send text";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Contact Number</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="1" name="1" onkeyup="deselectcheckbox(this.value)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><label><div id="divText">Send text</div></label></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="contact" id="checkbox" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've tried adding a wildcard to

```
(document.getElementById("1").value == "01*")
```

But it's not working, Please help

Comment: Why would a wildcard help with an exact comparison..?

Comment: Change your comparisone to use a substring of the first 2 digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want the checkbox to be enabled when the content starts with "07" you can check for that first and disable inside of the else block.

```
  if (document.getElementById("1").value.startsWith("07")) {
    $("#checkbox").attr("disabled", false);
    document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "Send text";
  }
  else
  {
    $("#checkbox").attr("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "Not able to send";
  }
```

Comment: @RickKap If it solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as an answer! ✅